# how to generate random number which is combination of letters as well as digit?

Tags: c#

how to generate random number which is combination of letters as well as digit? and which will not generate any duplicate number in C#.net

thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want to automatically create a symbol name, i.e. the name of a variable, type, method, &c.?

Comment: @Paul Ruane : i want a code which will not get duplicated in future. I want the code unique which i'm using  in my s/w . I'm storing that code in my database table whose datatype is varchar(5). It should be combination of alphabets from a-zA-Z & digits 0-9. will it possible by using following suggestions?

Comment: whilst it's possible to create random codes as you describe, there will always be a chance of collision with such a small number of characters (GUIDs use a time component, amongst other strategies to avoid collision). Preferable for five characters would be sequential codes. Could you not just use a database sequence to do this for you?

Comment: @Paul Ruane: No i don't want this happen with the help of database. And my code's datatype is varchar so how database can generate sequence number for record automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Guid generator to get a random sequence.

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString('N').SubString(0, [required length])
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [System.Guid structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)

Comment: Definition of a GUID = "a random number which is combination of letters as well as digit? and which will not generate any duplicate number in C#.net" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get 16 bytes from a crypto PRNG and encode in in hex.

Answer (score 0):

Which letters?

Depending on the answer to this, it may suffice to generate a normal random number, then convert it to *n*-base, where *n* is 10 + the number of letters you want to use.

E.g. with hexadecimal (16-base), you get the letters `A` to `F` on top of the digits. Using 36-base, you get all letters of the English alphabet.